# CodeIgniter login using passwordHash and passwordSalt

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, authentication

My question..The variable $salted returns a random UUID then md5's it.What I need for the login to work though is for the variable $salted to return the value of passwordSalt field in my database from the auth table that corresponds to `t1.PrincipalID = t2.UUID` .How do I give the variable $salted this value?

Basically how do i give a variable a value from my database without user input.Thank you.

code snippets..the essential part of my code.

my view...

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
<?php echo form_open('verifylogin'); ?>
<form>
    <input type="text" name="FirstName" placeholder="firstName">
    <input type="password" name="passwordHash" placeholder="Password">


    <input type="submit" name="login" class="login login-submit" value="Login">
</form></div>
```

my controller...

```
Function check_database($password)
{
    //Field validation succeeded.  Validate against database
    $firstName = $this->input->post('FirstName');
    $password = $this->input->post('passwordHash');




    //query the database
    $result = $this->users_model->login($firstName,$password);

    if($result)
    {
        $sess_array = array();
        foreach($result as $row)
        {
            $sess_array = array(
                'PrincipalID' => $row->PrincipalID,
                'FirstName' => $row->FirstName
            );
            $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);
        }
        return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('check_database', 'Invalid username or password');
        return false;
    }
}
```

my model..

```
function login($firstName,$password)
{




     $salted  = sprintf('%s', md5(_uuid()));
     $hash = md5(md5($password) . ":" . $salted);

    $this->db->select('PrincipalID, FirstName')
        ->from('useraccounts AS t1, auth AS t2')
        ->where('t1.PrincipalID = t2.UUID')
        ->where('t1.FirstName', $firstName)
          ->where('t2.passwordHash', $hash);

    $this -> db -> limit(1);

    $query = $this -> db -> get();

    if($query -> num_rows() == 1)
    {
        return $query->result();
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use tank_auth library which has everything ready :)
Second thing is that you should add add salt(for that you need to retrieve user salt from database) to given password and then encrypt it using hash function and only then try to validate it with a user in database

Comment: instead of creating your own salt and try to md5 your password, why don't you simply use password_hash function? http://ca2.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: If you're not rocking PHP 5.5 yet with the new `password_hash()` function you should use something like [Phpass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/). Don't try and figure out cryptography your self.

Comment: I didn't have the luxury of creating the database and all these functions would be great.I am trying to create a user control system for a online multiplayer game and  this is how they store their passwords .An auth table with passowrdhash and passwordSalt among other fields and a useraccounts table with firstName ,last name etc etc..where each primary key is identified by a UUID which correspond to each other.The reason i cant change the database is because users can register in game and this is how it links back to its database.I think the game was created before PHP.5.5.Thanks for the help.